# How to solve the issue of NetSuite Restlet timeout limit issue?

Tags: javascript, oracle, timeout, netsuite, restlet

Now I am working on NetSuite Restlet for the first time.
I have the following data retrieved from savedSearch.

```json
{
  "recordType": "receipt",
  "id": "sample-id",
  "values": {
    "customer.customerid": "sample-id",
    "customer.customercompany": "sample-customercompany", 
    "customer.addressone": "sample-addressone",
    "customer.addresstwo": "sample-addresstwo",
    "customer.addresscity": "sample-addresscity",
    "customer.addressstate": "sample-addressstate",
    "country": "Australia",
    "transacitionrecordid": "sample-id",
    "unit": "Dollar",
    "total": "120"
  }
}
```

And I have to loop the resultsets and push each record to the array and return the array at the end.
There are no fields that I can drop. All the fields have to be included.

The problem is that the number of records is roughly 31,000.
When I run my script, the execution goes over 5 mins which is the Restlet execution time limit.
Here is my script.

```js
define(['N/search'], function(search) {
  function get(event) {
    var saved = search.load({ id: "search-id" });
    var searchResultSet = saved.run();
    
    var results = [];
    var start = 0;
    
    do {
      searchRecords = searchResultSet.getRange({ start: start, end: start + 1000 });
      start = start + 1000;
      results.concat(searchRecords);
    } while(results.length);

    return JSON.stringify(results); // return as string for now to see the output on browser
  }
  
  return {
    get: get
  };
})
```

This is what my script looks like.

Ideally, I call this script once and return the whole 31,000 records of data.

However, due to the execution limit, I am thinking of passing a parameter(works as a pointer?index?cursor) and passing this variable to `getRange` function as a starting index.
I have tested and I can call for 10,000 records. So call this script 3 times by passing the parameter like 0, 10000, 20000.

But is there any better way to solve this issue? What I am really looking for is to call this script only once and return 31,000 records without having the issue of timeout.

Can I have any suggestions, please?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a map reduce script type. I am not sure what the overall result you are trying to achieve is but in general MapReduce scripts are made for processing large amounts of data.

The script can be scheduled OR you can trigger it using N/Task *(seems like this is what you need if you want to trigger it from the RESTLET)*

MapReduce scripts have 4 native functions. Each function has its own usage limit each time it is triggered which makes it ideal for processing large amounts of data like this.
The first is used for generating the dataset *(you can return a search: return search.create({}) )*
Second is for grouping data - it will run once per search result.
Third is for executing code on the data - it will run once per unique key that was passed from the previous funciton.
Fourth is for summarizing the script. You can catch errors here etc.

It is possible that 31k results will be to large for the first function to query in which case you can split it into sections. For example get up to 5k results and then in the summarize check if there are still more results to process and if there are trigger the script again (to do this you will need multiple deployments and a marker on the transaction to tell you that it was updated OR a global field which holds the the last chunk of data that was processed)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. but actually, i found out that my code was not efficient enough. seems like `getRenge` function to `runPage` and it works fine now.

Comment: did you replace `run` with `runPage` or `getRange` with `runPage`

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Split it in smaller batches if you still want to use the Restlet to do the job, receive smaller amount of records .
2. Write the data you receive to a custom record LONG TEXT field JSON stringified , if they are more than a 1,000,000 characters  and have a map reduce process these records.
   3.create a MAP/Reduce TASK and pass the data stringified in the parameters of the deployment. You can have multiple deployments if one is not enough.

If your purpose ( as i havent clearly understood ) is to call the Restlet to retrieve data from NS , then simply add pagination .

page 1 could be 0-1000 page2 would be page1 end + 1000 and in every response from your restlet just provide the total number of results and the total number of pages . This way in your app that calls the restlet you can simply make a loop to gather all the results from each page.